# TypeScript 3.5: How to update object properties using indexer notation?

Tags: typescript

Before TS 3.5 I was able to do:

```js
type Nullable<T> = T | undefined;
type KeyOf<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>;
type ExcludeKey<T, K extends KeyOf<T>, E> = T[K] extends Nullable<E> ? never : K;
type ExtractKey<T, K extends KeyOf<T>, E> = T[K] extends Nullable<E>  ? K : never;
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in KeyOf<T>]: ExcludeKey<T, K, Function>; }[KeyOf<T>];
type TestKey = NonFunctionPropertyNames<Test>;
type TestKeyList = TestKey[];

class Test {
  name!: string;
  age?: number;
  birthDate?: Date;

  resetSomeField(key: TestKey): void {
    this[key] = undefined;    
  }

  resetAllFields(): void {
    const keys = Object.keys(this) as TestKeyList;
    keys.forEach(this.resetSomeField);
  }
}
```

But after upgrade to 3.5.3 the line

```js
this[key] = undefined;
```

gives me an error:

> error TS2322: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.

I know that this behavior is now intended and caused by one of the breaking changes introduced in 3.5:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types

But workaround mentioned in it does not work for me - since I have objects with hundreds of properties of different type. And I do not want to introduce separate reset function for each set of properties of the same type, as suggested there.

I wasn't able to find a compiler option to turn this new behavior as well.

Optionally, I can use the previous TS version. But this is a temporary solution, obviously.

So could someone suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: Btw, what result do you expect if `key = 'resetSomeField'`?

Comment: I just didn't want to complicate the code, but if you asked - in current version key can be only `"age" | "name" | "birthDate"`

Comment: @AntonZhaparov I don't get the same error unless there are some fields that are mandatory (which your example does not have)

Comment: Yep, but in newer TS and logically - it includes all the methods as well.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, good catch, thanks. I've made changes to example.

Comment: You are intentionally writing unsound code, where fields which cannot be `undefined` are being set to `undefined`.  As of TS3.5 the compiler catches this for you.  If you really want to ignore it, then you can use a type assertion like `(this as any)[key] = undefined` or `this[key] = undefined!`.  If you want to fix it, then you should restrict `key` to be only those keys which cannot be `undefined`, or you should make all properties optional.  If you want one of those turned into an answer (except the last one, which is already an answer), let me know.

Comment: @jcalz, thank you for input. Actually, in the real code, `key` will always reference the nullable field. Now I think that I should better ask how to construct the type, that contains only nullable field names - and then set is as an input to `resetSomeField`. But this does not cover the case with `setSomeField(key, value)`. At the moment being, I went the anycast way, to resolve the issue quickly - so you can convert it into answer, if you want.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your `name!` field is required (by the non-null assertion operator `!`).  If you change it to `?` then the Typescript error goes away.

before:
[image: before]
after:
[image: after]

```
class Test {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
  birthDate?: Date;

  resetSomeField(this: Test, key: TestKey): void {
    this[key] = undefined
  }
...
```

[Play with it here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgGwQQwEYIgHgCoD4oC8U2UAPlHAHYAmEAZgJaUTUDcAUKJFANIQgB5OjnxEAogA9gAJ2QBjYJgDW-APZ1iAGigBnGUwDmuDl2iS5COLT4gc2nlAhSINHb35CR2saOIBtHgBdR2dXWEQUdCwfKAB+KGYANwhpKAAuXhNwMylZBRs7XhDgF2o3G088b19sAOCnErD4JDQMTBi4ooyklKzuGFVKADEqBQZBgAVpVUhpUBhkAFsIHRFCKABvKACoJndBYTxAjPNLa35Cnm0RyjHB4ygAXwCPQ9xAvuhsFeAbdYHhqNgONKFMZil5ksVjgfsZONliD8bAAZBh6dbfPQ2PwfdjsCzIHRuTHATbsKAJKGxDJ6aSGDgU5AGCDUhJwRaoXrkqCoBhzAAWABFkCVWcKShxudIVhBgABlVTLIYMCAIagACmA-LRGRJ2hUIF1SP4AEoMolVAxqGSKRStWi-AbgkQqLRGMxqNzHniKdKdLKAIJIZWqsrqs1QC1Wm22uSDdEGtxEASoABWEAUADpE5rtToTVBCYisfxUXoGbbE5m6KppGJ5Pzc2jM37ZQqlSq1SaK97vUA)

Comment: Since TS does not have null-conditional operator (?.) this solution does not sound feasible - with this approach I will have to rewrite all my code with
`if (obj.name != null) {
 // something happens here
}`

Comment: Please replace (or supplement) images of code with the text of the code.  Images cannot be searched or copy/pasted easily.   Thanks!

Comment: But you are already having that issue, because when you call `resetAllFields()` that is setting `object.name = undefined`

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps the wrong thing from a technical level but it is such a pain that I have gone with it:

```
 (object[key] as any) = newVal;
```